# Startup Script CMD Output results to UNC path

Tags: csv, cmd, startup, unc

We're doing an audit and we want to know which asset tags have which service tags.

The plan is to append a startup script that when triggered, sends the hostname, svc tag and model number to a .csv which is located on a server share.

Here is a snippet:

```
net use x: "\\server\path"

wmic os get csname >> x:\2016Audit.csv

wmic csproduct get identifyingnumber,name >> x:\2016Audit.csv

net use x: /delete
```

So we map the UNC path locally, run the two WMIC commands, write the results to .csv on the mapped drive, and then delete the mapped drive.

This works fine when run from within Windows (Windows 7 Pro x86) however run as a startup script the script fails. The script itself runs, I know this for a fact, but the results aren't written to the server share.

Any ideas?

Or, if you can think of an entirely different way to approach this, let me know. Bare in mind that we have 1500 PC's.

Thanks,

Elliott

Answer (score 1):

```
wmic os get csname >> "\\server\path\2016Audit.csv"

wmic csproduct get identifyingnumber,name >> "\\server\path\2016Audit.csv"
```

Also type `wmic /output /?` and `wmic /append /?` for help on wmic own writing to file ability.

Here's a sample command that shows wmic capabilities.

```
wmic /node:"@%userprofile%\desktop\ComputerName.txt" /output:"%userprofile%\desktop\NicSpeed.html" /failfast:on nic where (PhysicalAdapter=TRUE and Speed!=100000000) get systemname,speed,caption /format:htable
```

Mapped drives are for old programs.

```
C:\Users\User>wmic csproduct get identifyingnumber,name  /format:csv

Node,IdentifyingNumber,Name
DESKTOP-UCDGI39,CND5382Y72,HP Notebook
```

See `wmic /format /?`.

When querying computers on a network use the `/failfast` switch. It will skip unavailable computers quickly. See `wmic /failfast /?`.

Use `net view` to get a list of computers to use in the node command. Remove `\\` from the file. See `wmic /node /?`.

Here's a sample computerlist.txt, you can mix and match computer names and ip addresses.

```
serenity
127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It'd be really nifty if I could combine wmic commands so that in a CSV i have three columns; one for os csname (hostname), one for csproduct identifying number (service tag) and one for csproduct name (model number). Is this possible at all?

Comment: See `/format` switch. I edited my answer. So `wmic /format /?`